# Is it possible to map a hotkey to "compare to each other" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The key mapping options in eclipse are voluminous, but they don't seem to include "compare to each other." Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0. As shown below, uncheck all the filters and then you will see the option - "Compare with each other"

[image: Eclipse Keys - Filters]

Comment: Never underestimate the hidden features of eclipse. I never clicked the filters button. Although when I set it, I find my hotkey doesn't actually trigger the function. :-(

Comment: I am assigning a hot-key to compare with each other, but it is not working, any idea why? I am using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: For me "Compare with each other" also didn't work, but "Compare With Other Resource" did. It triggers a dialog, which can be quickly confirmed with TAB followed by ENTER.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no shortcut, but you can open the Preferences (General / **[Keys](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/keyboardshortcuts.htm)**), type "Compare", and assign a shortcut there.

(two commands can fit your description:

- either to 'Compare With Another Branch or Version, in a CVS context
- or "**Compare With Other Resource**": Compare resources, clipboard contents or editors, which is certainly what "`Compare to > Each other`" is about )

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/keys1.png))</sub>

Comment: My various versions of eclipse (ganymede) don't have "compare with other resource."

Answer (score 0):

After highlighting 2 files or folders in the browser 
get the context menu by clicking with the right mouse button or the key next to your right ctrl button
and type a (comp**a**re) and then
e (**e**ach other)

Comment: yeah, but that's not what a hotkey is. a hotkey is where you specify a one-or-two key stroke sequence to avoid having to do all that. Thanks anyway.